# How to generate groovydoc from jenkins global library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries, groovydoc

I have a [jenkins global library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) and I want to document it. I want to use groovydoc.

The library contains classes and global vars

```
src/<package-name>
vars
```

Generating documentation for the classes is no problem:

```
groovydoc -sourcepath src -d doc 'main.pipeline' '*.groovy'
```

But how can I generate documentation for the vars?

Answer (score 4):

To ensure everything was reported in the right packages, without having to enumerate all the packages, I used:

```
mkdir -p doc/

groovydoc -d doc -private -nomainforscripts -sourcepath src:vars \
    $(find src/ vars/ -name \*.groovy -printf '%P\n')
```

This incantation convinces Groovydoc to get the packages right without requiring me to tediously list them all, which is the main challenge.

If your `find` doesn't have `-printf`, replace `-printf '%P\n'` with `| cut -d '/' -f 2-`. The effect is the same; strip the leading `src/` or `vars/`.

Comment: Linux or windows soloution?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

```
groovydoc -d docs -sourcepath "src;." my.package vars
```

Exports everything in `vars` as DefaultPackage and `my.package` contained in the `src` folder.

Comment: THis is working but only one packet is taken instead of all packet

Answer (score 1):

Maven solution:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
    <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>addSources</goal>
          <goal>addTestSources</goal>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>compileTests</goal>
          <goal>groovydoc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <sources>
        <source>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/vars</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
          </includes>
        </source>
        <source>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
          </includes>
        </source>
      </sources>
      <testSources>
        <testSource>
          <directory>${project.basedir}/test</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
          </includes>
        </testSource>
      </testSources>
      <docTitle>Jenkins Shared Libs</docTitle>
      <header>${titre}</header>
      <footer>${titre}</footer>
      <windowTitle>${titre}</windowTitle>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem at work today and sadly can't try my solution now, but try using the directory containing both `src` and `vars` as `sourcepath`. Then you can reference your `src` and `vars` subdirectories in your command like this:

```
groovydoc -sourcepath [PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB] -d doc src\ vars\
```

If that doesnt work, try referencing each package seperately somewhat like this:

```
groovydoc -sourcepath [PATH_TO_YOUR_LIB] -d doc src\org.foo.some_package src\org.foo.some_other_package vars\
```

Alternatively, or as a workaround, you could use the IntelliJ IDE and its "Generate GroovyDoc..."-Tool:

1. Start IntelliJ and open any Groovy project (create a new one if there isnt an existing one)
2. From the menu bar `Tools > Generate GroovyDoc...`
3. Choose your source path containing your jenkins pipeline library as `Input directory` (containing both `src` and `vars`) and any path as `Output directory`
4. Press `Start`
5. GroovyDoc should be in the specified `Output directory`

Comment: The output I get is completely unusable. The structure of the shared libraries is not standard groovy. For example the files in /vars are not classes but just methods listed in a file.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue. i just needed an overview with parameters. I know there is lots of space for improvement, but works for my usecase:

```
import groovy.io.FileType
import java.util.regex.*;

class DocGenerator {
    String run(String root_path) {


        def list = []

        def dir = new File(root_path)
        dir.eachFileRecurse(FileType.FILES) { file ->
            if (file.name.contains("groovy"))
                list << file
        }

        String output = "| Method | Doc |\n"
        output += "| ------ | ------ |\n"

        list.each {
            output += "| ${it.name.replace(".groovy","")} | ${getComment(it.text.replace("\r\n","<br>"))} |\n"
        }

        println(output)
        return output
    }

    String getComment(String txt) {


        String re1 = "(\\/\\*[\\d\\D]*?\\*\\/)";    // C Comment 1
        String re2 = ".*?";    // Non-greedy match on filler
        String re3 = "def";    // Word 1
        String re4 = ".*?";    // Non-greedy match on filler
        String re5 = "call";    // Word 2

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
        if (m.find()) {
            String ccomment1 = m.group(1);

            return m.group(1)
        }

    }

}

app = new DocGenerator()
app.run "C:\\Git\\JenkinsSharedLibrary\\vars"
```

My output was intended to be added to an **readme.md**. But i think you get the point